# Prevent resizing of button during transition of icon

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

As of now my button gets larger during the transition. My goal is to have the arrow go from left to right without having the actual button resizing. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g8n4y7cp/)

I tried with `max-width: 100%` on the button but this solution makes the transition ugly.

HTML

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary">
    Dont make me larger
    <i class="arrow-right"></i>
</a>
```

CSS

```
.arrow-right {
    /* STYLING */
  margin-left: 10px;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;
      border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
      display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);

    /* TRANSITION */
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: 0.5s;
}

.btn-primary:hover .arrow-right {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/6yc5Lztw/1/ if you set the button to position relative and set the arrow to position absolute, you can get the button's size to stay the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the button to be relative positioned and then apply a `left` value on hover, as follows:

```
    .arrow-right {
    /* STYLING */
    margin-left: 10px;
    border: solid #fff;
    border-radius: 1px;
    border-width: 0 3px 3px 0;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    /* TRANSITION */
    -webkit-transition: 0.5s; /* Safari */
    transition: 0.5s;

    /* New Code */
    position:relative;
    left:0
}

.btn-primary:hover .arrow-right {
    left:5px
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/du0rLphc/1/

Answer (score 1):

one way to get this to work is to set the button to `position relative` and set the arrow to `position absolute`, you can get the button's size to stay the same:

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/6yc5Lztw/1

The problem with this approach is you have to figure out how far down the arrow should be using pixels and the `top` property, so different button heights will not automatically work here

another way is to add padding to the right of the button and when you hover you remove the same amount of pixels of padding as you add amount of margin to the arrow. Basically I added `20px of padding-right` to the button, and since the arrow adds `5px or margin` when hovered, I make the `padding right` of the button `15px` when hovered

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmadabdul3/6yc5Lztw/4/

this solution will always keep the arrow and text aligned if you have your css set up correctly with something like:

```
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
```